# The while loop cannot progress pass i = 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have a small algorithm like this one.

[image: The flowchart]

I coded it in python

```
import pandas as pd
raw = pd.read_csv

i = 0
T = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Values'])
singleT = raw.mean() + raw.std()
T = T.append(singleT, ignore_index=True)

if i == 0:
    raw = raw.where(raw<T.iloc[i,:])
    i += 1

while True:
    singleT = raw.mean() + raw.std()
    T = T.append(singleT, ignore_index=True)
    if T.iloc[i,:].values == T.iloc[i-1,:].values:
        break
    background = T.iloc[i,:].values
else:
    raw = raw.where(raw<T.iloc[i,:])
    i += 1
    print ('iteration{:02}'.format(i))
```

However, the loop didn't get pass i = 1 and keep repeating, the whole T array is filled with value when i = 1. I tried several modifications to my code but they also didn't work at all.

Any advice on how to fix this problem would be appreciated!
Thank you very much

Edit: I have inserted one tab for the last 4 lines, as you guys suggested to make sure the `else` belong to `while`, but now it has syntax invalid error

Edit2: Here is the correct code for this problem, it will not enter the infinite loop.

```
i = 0
T = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Pulse counts'])
singleT = raw.mean() + raw.std()
T = T.append(singleT, ignore_index=True)

if i == 0:
    filtered = raw.where(raw<T.iloc[i,:])
    i += 1

while True:
    singleT = filtered.mean() + filtered.std()
    T = T.append(singleT, ignore_index=True)
    if T.iloc[i,:].values == T.iloc[i-1,:].values or T.iloc[i-1,:].values == 0:
        background = T.iloc[i-1,:].values
        break
    else:
        filtered = filtered.where(filtered<T.iloc[i,:])
        print ('iteration{}'.format(i))
    i += 1
```

Comment: the broken indentation could hide the real issue. Please fix it.

Comment: also where is `i` initialized? this isn't a [mcve]

Comment: yeah, I'm so sorry, I pasted the wrong code. And yes, that's code failed by the wrong indentation on else, but I haven't been able to fix it yet

Comment: Do you really need to write this using `numpy`/`pandas` - I'd have thought for a simple flowchart like that - something in pure python would be much simpler?

Comment: Because I'm pretty new to code, I just want to make sure that I'm using the right syntax for the pandas library. It's just a habbit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
import pandas as pd
raw = pd.read_csv

i = 0
T = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Values'])
singleT = raw.mean() + raw.std()
T = T.append(singleT, ignore_index=True)

while True:
    singleT = raw.mean() + raw.std()
    T = T.append(singleT, ignore_index=True)
    if T.iloc[i,:].values == T.iloc[i-1,:].values:
        background = T.iloc[i,:].values
        break       
    else:
        raw = raw.where(raw<T.iloc[i,:])
        #i += 1
        print ('iteration{:02}'.format(i))
    i += 1
```

Comment: It works! However, I now have a problem when the T value reaches 0, it will not stop the loop, but instead continue infinitely with nan value. 
I know this may be a little more than the question, but do you have any suggestion to this issue?

Comment: You have to use `i += 1` outside of  `else` to stop infinite loop. Check my edit code.

Comment: I updated the corrected code in the question, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

if your indentation is correct, the `else` part:

```
else:
    raw = raw.where(raw<T.iloc[i,:])
    i += 1
    print ('iteration{:02}'.format(i))
```

doesn't belong to the `if` but to the `while`, which has a different meaning: it is executed only if loop ends without a `break` (less-known feature, also available with `for` which saves the need to define a flag when `break` has been reached)

So `i` is never incremented: infinite loop.

Comment: I have just tried to insert one Tab for all lines down from else:, but it resulted in invalid syntax.
This part now looks like:

`    while True:`
`        singleT = raw.mean() + raw.std()`
`        T = T.append(singleT, ignore_index=True)`
`        if T.iloc[i,:].values == T.iloc[i-1,:].values:`
`            break`
`        background = T.iloc[i,:].values`
`        else:`
`            raw = raw.where(raw<T.iloc[i,:])`
`            i += 1`
`            print ('iteration{:02}'.format(i))`

Comment: understand that pasting python code in oneline comment isn't very useful...